# Different size of div in browser and in css

Tags: css

I added simple div just to test it

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:270px;">
      text 
</div>
```

When I make print screen and paste it to photoshop it says width of div is 243px not 270px. I can't figure it out why.

EDIT:
There is no css or javascript just that div in blank html document

Comment: Sounds like some padding could have been applied to it. Have you reset your CSS?

Comment: there is no other CSS files. Just that line of code in blank html document

Comment: Which browser? Mozilla? Chrome? IE?

Comment: It happens in chrome only

Comment: Not working when using localhost :O

Answer (score 1):

Each browser applies some styling to all elements. On top of that you set your own CSS properties which get combined with them. You should use a reset stylesheet to get rid of any standard styling: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: * {margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px;} should be sufficient.

Comment: For this specific example yes, for larger things the one I provided might not be enough though.

Comment: Maybe a position:absolute; could save the day but not good for mobile maybe?